# Finding a non-negative solution to an integer system of linear equations

Tags: ds.algorithms, linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times m$ integer matrix and consider the system of equations $Ax = b$ where $b$ is an integer vector. I want to find a solution $x$, assuming one exists, such that the components of $x$ are non-negative integers.

What is the complexity of this problem? Is there a known algorithm that finds such a solution, or returns false if none exist?

Comment: It came up studying another problem on simplicial complexes. In this case $A$ is the boundary matrix and I am looking for a chain with non-negative coefficients whose boundary is $b$. It didn't seem straightforward to me, could you elaborate on why you think it is?

Answer (score 1):

This is NP-hard, by reduction from ILP feasibility.  Deciding feasibility of an ILP instance is NP-hard, so your problem is, too.

You can convert each inequality $a_1 x_1 + \dots + a_n x_n \ge b$ into an equality using a [slack variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_variable) $s \ge 0$:

$$a_1 x_1 + \dots + a_n x_n - s = b.$$

You can arrange for all variables to be non-negative by defining $x_i = x_i^+ - x_i^-$ where the variables $x_i^+,x_i^-$ are non-negative and replacing each $x_i$ with $x_i^+ - x_i^-$.

This transformation turns a system of $m$ linear inequalities in $n$ integer variables into a system of $m+n$ linear inequalities in $2n+m$ non-negative integer variables.  Thus the result has exactly the form of your problem.